# Remove PWA and install again

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I have 2 questions about PWA.

1. I have installed PWA long time ago, than in a half year I have removed it from main screen like common application. Now i cant installed it from my browser. Chrome do not show popup and also do not fire event 'beforeinstallprompt'. How i can fix it?
2. When i see chrome installation PWA popup and push close button, pop up will never show up again. How come? How to show this pop up all the time?

My manifest:

```
{
"name": "Name of app",
"short_name": "Name of app",
"theme_color": "#55525d",
"background_color": "#275981",
"display": "standalone",
"start_url": "/",
"scope": "/",
"icons": [
    {
        "src": "\/android-icon-36.png",
        "sizes": "36x36",
        "type": "image\/png"
    },
    {
        "src": "\/android-icon-48.png",
        "sizes": "48x48",
        "type": "image\/png"
    },
    {
        "src": "\/android-icon-72.png",
        "sizes": "72x72",
        "type": "image\/png"
    },
    {
        "src": "\/android-icon-96.png",
        "sizes": "96x96",
        "type": "image\/png"
    },
    {
        "src": "\/android-icon-144.png",
        "sizes": "144x144",
        "type": "image\/png"
    },
    {
        "src": "\/android-icon-192.png",
        "sizes": "192x192",
        "type": "image\/png"
    },
    {
        "src": "\/android-icon-512.png",
        "sizes": "512x512",
        "type": "image\/png"
    }
]
```

}

All ok with PWA. Chrome do not show any errors in lightroom.

Comment: This problem only occur in your own website ? Do you ever try other website that you know it has PWA ? because I think it is come from your browser

Comment: Mobile or desktop? Are you sure you have uninstalled and TOTALLY cleared your browser's cache?

Comment: Yes i am sure. Pop up do not appears i can install it if i push 3 dots in chrome and push 'Add to home'.

Comment: If you are doing "Add to Home", you are probably just adding a shortcut to a website to your desktop. Not A PWA.

Comment: No i think it is a PWA. Because it opens like standalone real app.

Answer (score 1):

For question 1, assuming you're using Android, when you removed the app from your homescreen did you "remove" or "uninstall"? It might be that the app was removed but is in fact still installed so you won't get prompted to reinstall. In the Chrome three dot menu, does it show "Open in *Your_App_Name*" or "Install "*Your_App_Name*"? If it shows "Open in...", it is still installed.

For question 2, that sounds like Chrome is just remembering that you chose not to install it. IMO it sounds like it would be a bad user experience to force an install popup every load, especially after the user has chosen to ignore it. Clearing browser data in the Chrome app settings would bring it back.

Comment: 1) I have uninstalled it. But after that i can install it again. Just push 3 dots in chrome and choose 'add to home page' but pop up still do not show up... 
2) Nothing helps:) I think i should use events that chrome provide.

Comment: Indeed, clearing browser data/history worked. Found an answer about this here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47544527/2471080

Comment: @user5384437 it's probably because when you installed it the first time, it ALSO added a key to localstorage that hides the popup. If you uninstall it AND clear the browser cache, does that bring it back?